# mysql query; select all items in category tree

Tags: mysql

I have a table with categories, where a category can have a parentid (is child of other category). When i want to filter items on a parent category id, I want the query to include all child categories.

Lets say I have this category structure:

```
id || title     || parentid
1  || Sports    || 0
2  || Tennis    || 1
3  || Wimbledon || 2
```

Now I have an article in the category Wimbledon. And I want to display all articles in the category sport.

```
SELECT item.* FROM #table_items AS item WHERE item.catid = 1;
```

The above query doesn't return the article in the category Wimbledon. Is this possible?

Comment: In Oracle, you have CONNECT BY PRIOR, but I don't think MySQL supports this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution I was searching for. Lets say i want to display all items in a category with id 12:

```
SELECT item.* FROM #table_items AS item
LEFT JOIN #__foc_shop_categories AS cat1 ON (cat1.id = item.catid)
LEFT JOIN #__foc_shop_categories AS cat2 ON (cat1.parentid = cat2.id)
... (and so on for more depth)

WHERE (cat1.id = 12 OR cat2.id = 12 OR ...)
GROUP BY item.id
```

It results all items in the category and the nested categories.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item.* FROM #table_items AS item,#categories as catg
WHERE item.parentid = cat.parentid;
```

Comment: Doesn't work... The item table has an field 'catid', which references an category.

Comment: table item has fields id || title || catid, where catid links to the id field in the category table.